# Unable to ping IPV6 default Gateway on OpenSuse 13.2

Tags: linux, opensuse, ipv6

I have configured IPv4 and IPv6 addresses on eth0 on OpenSuse 13.2 and edited `/etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-eth0` to support IPv6

The contents of my file are as below

```
BOOTPROTO='static'
BROADCAST=''
ETHTOOL_OPTIONS=''
IPADDR='10.54.48.255/23'
MTU=''
NAME='Ethernet Card 0'
NETWORK=''
REMOTE_IPADDR=''
STARTMODE='auto'
GATEWAY='10.54.48.1'
IPADDR_0='fd00:10:6b50:4300::ff'
PREFIXLEN_0=60
```

As you see, IPv4 has a default gateway. Is it possible to configure a default gateway to V6 too in the same file?

I am able to ping default gateway of V4, but I always need to restart the network to ping the default gateway on V6, which works for some time, and again it stops pinging.

ifconfig Looks like this

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:E5:20:3C
          inet addr:10.54.48.255  Bcast:10.54.49.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:fee5:203c/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: fd00:10:6b50:4300::ff/60 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:103365694 errors:0 dropped:276091 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:466135 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:6540795773 (6237.7 Mb)  TX bytes:45719361 (43.6 Mb)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:17648 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:17648 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:2079487 (1.9 Mb)  TX bytes:2079487 (1.9 Mb)
```

Comment: Also,

I have added these in /etc/sysconfig/network/routes

default 10.54.48.1 - -
default fd00:10:6b50:4300::1 - -

Comment: Please add the output of `ifconfig`

Comment: Added Output of ifconfig

Answer (score 0):

Open the `/etc/sysconfig/network` and add the following line:

```
NETWORKING_IPV6=yes
```

Then edit the `/etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-eth0` file by adding:

```
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6ADDR=<IPv6-IP-Address>
IPV6_DEFAULTGW=<IPv6-IP-Gateway-Address>
```

Restart networking:

```
service network restart
```

Comment: openSuse does not have /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/
The File system on OpenSuse is /etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-eth0

I do not know if setting IPV6 address as you mentioned going to work